# Most efficient way to remove darker border around gaussian blur

Tags: opengl, glsl

So I am drawing a blurred image in **opengl**, using the standard gaussian blur formula.
[gaussian blur wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_blur)

This works perfectly fine. The problem like many others have is the border. Since the framebuffer only contains black outside of the buffer created it will cause a dark edge. [visual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IKkDo.png)

I've seen people mentioning that you can draw the image with a mirror.[mirror](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bLURi.png)
From my understanding, this would require calculating / doubling the size of the framebuffer and would make opengl draw a lot more than otherwise needed.

Would there be a better way to go about this.

I was also considering just flipping a pixel if its out of bounds. [flip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wyKDm.png)

This would require another 2-4 calculations for each pixel.

Are there any better ways to do this, or have I missed some really useful documentation.

Just to recap, I'm trying to find out what are existing / optimized solutions to removing the darkened border on gaussian blurred images.

Comment: Have you tried setting the wrap mode to `'GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE`?

Answer (score -2):

OpenGL has a built-in way to wrap textures automatically when sampling from them. There is no need to double the framebuffer:

```
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
```

Comment: How would `GL_REPEAT` solve the problem? Afaik, repeating the texture will cause ghosting artefacts from objects on the other side of the screen.

Comment: When sampling points outside the texture inside the blur shader, the texture will simply be repeated infinitely, instead of having an infinite black border. Obviously this is problematic if the texture being blurred isn't very uniform at the edges (the edges will seem to bleed into their opposite edges), but in many cases this will suffice.

Comment: If the black border is the problem, then why not repeat the last Texel with `GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE` or at least use `GL_MIRROR_REPEAT` to sample texels from the same side?